# Parallelizing tensor operations in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I'm trying to parallelize different tensor operations. I'm aware that `tf.vectorized_map` and/or `tf.map_fn` can parallelize input tensor(s) with respect to their first axis, but that's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to parallelize a for loop on a set of tensors with possibly different shapes.

```py
a = tf.ones((2))
b = tf.ones((2,2))
list_of_tensors = [a,b*2,a*3]
for t in list_of_tensors:
    # some operation on t which may vary depending on its shape
```

Is there a possible way to parallelize this for loop on GPU with TensorFlow? (I'm open to any other library if possible i.e. JAX, numba etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: You may be able to achieve this with `tf.ragged` and `map_fn`...? `tf.ragged` specifically supports `map_fn` ( https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor ).

Comment: I believe ragged tensor requires the tensors inside to have same shape if the input is not a python object. e.g. 
`
a = tf.ones((2));
b = tf.ones((2,2));
t = [[a,b*2,a*3],[a*4,a*5,b*6],[b*7,a*8,a*9]];
tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(t)
`
does not work. Please do correct me if I'm missing something

Comment: In the linked webpage to `tf.ragged` I don't see how your `t` is different from the example `digits` on the webpage? Can you not simply `tf.ragged.constant([[a,b*2,a*3],[a*4,a*5,b*6],[b*7,a*8,a*9]])`? (I don't have a REPL to try right now)

Comment: It gives the following error: `ValueError: all scalar values must have the same nesting depth` It does work when `a` and `b` are scalars but in my case, they are tensors with different shapes.

Comment: Ahhh I see. This may be a terrible "solution" but you could flatten all of your tensors to the same rank and prepend this original shape to their flattened representation. Then have your map function reshape them and then perform whatever function you require. It's not pretty but it may achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/vectorized_map),

> The shape and dtype of any intermediate or output tensors in the
> computation of fn should not depend on the input to fn.

I'm struggling with this problem myself.  I think the answer is one suggested in the comments: If you know the maximum length that your tensor can have, represent the variable length tensor by the maximum length tensor plus an integer which gives the actual length of the tensor.  Whether this will be useful at all depends on the meaning of "any intermediate", because at some point you may still need the result of the actual shorter length tensor in your computation.  It's a bit of a tail-chasing exercise.  This part of Tensorflow is extremely frustrating, it's very very hacky to get things to work that should be easy, especially in the realm of obtaining true parallelism on the GPU for deterministic matrix algorithms, outside of the context of machine learning.

[This](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/autograph/experimental/set_loop_options) might work inside the loop:

```
tf.autograph.experimental.set_loop_options(
    shape_invariants=[(v, tf.TensorShape([None]))]
)
```